# testRunner results are not coherent

Tags: soapui, ready-api

I'm currently facing a problem with ReadyAPI testRunner results.
In order to design my tests, I use a small teardown script in order to check my testCase's steps status:

```
log.info "****************** EXECUTION SUMMARY *****"
log.info "nb test steps = "+ testRunner.getTestCase().getTestStepCount()
        for (testStep in testRunner.getResults()){
            log.info "step " + testStep.getTestStep().getName() + " : " + testStep.getStatus()
        }
log.info "**********************************************"
```

In most of my tests it fits my requirements but I have a test that gives me incoherent results, ie. It contains 10 steps and displays results for only the five latest

```
:INFO:nb steps : 10
:INFO:step pending or success : OK
:INFO:step while pending : OK
:INFO:step GetPendingRequest - terminated : OK
:INFO:step while not terminated : OK
:INFO:step disconnect : OK
```

I have another test from another testSuite which contains similar test structure and which gives me a correct output.
I event tried to modify both testCases in order to have the same sequence but I still have the problem.

Has someone already been through an issue like this one  ?
Any help appreciated

here is a screenshot : Copy of TTM API has the problem, Copy of Use Cases don't 
[image: project]

Comment: Screen shot of your test case with steps? Could be because not all steps have result.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like not all your steps have results. You can add `testRunner.getResults().size()` to your teardown script to confirm how many of your steps have results.

I can't find confirmation on when a step result is created, but the documentation for `getResults()` says

> it "Gets the accumulated results so far; each TestStep returns a TestStepResult when running."

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that one, but it shows that only 5 results are available, with no clue on what's wrong  :(

Comment: could you try adding a delay before the end of the test case to see if makes any difference?

Comment: I did, it doesn't make any difference :(

Comment: can you trying adding `for(stepsWithResults in testRunner.getResults()){
 log.info(stepsWithResults.getTestStep().getName())
}` to your teardown script. It will log out the test step names for each of the results you have.